# Camera Raw (Photoshop) profile for Canon 5D II?

Tags: photoshop, raw, canon-5d-mark-ii

When opening raw files in Canon Digital Photo Professional then all settings from camera are loaded inside DPP. Is it possible to load camera settings inside Camera Raw? By default, Camera Raw adds lot of contrast and color is completely different.

Comment: Hi ile. Does http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/why-do-my-photos-look-different-in-photoshop-lightroom-vs-canon-eos-utility-in-ca answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

On the camera profiles tab of ACR there will be a dropdown list with various profile selections. There will be an "Adobe Standard" and likely a handful of Canon ones that you can try out as a starting point for raw development. If you find one that is similar to DPP, then you can set it as a default (I don't have ACR in front of me right now to give specific guidance on that). Better yet, you may find a different profile that you like better than either... :)

Anyways, ACR gives you some options, but not shooting Canon, I can't say what the exact list of profiles will look like for you.

Comment: Also - make sure to get all the updates from Adobe.  I wasn't able to access all my camera profiles until I did that.