# Camera JPG Post Processing

Tags: darktable

I was just reading the responses to a question as to why RAW images look different in lightable and darkroom in Darktable (due to the in camera post processing taking place for JPG files) and I would like to know a little more about this conversion process.
I thought the camera only compresses the image when it converts the RAW file to a JPG? But the process also involves manipulating the tones of the image using some algorithm whether I like it or not. Why does it do this? It looks better than the RAW file, why doesn't the RAW file look as good?

[Why does the appearance of RAW files change when switching from "lighttable" to "darkroom" in Darktable?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45695/why-does-the-appearance-of-raw-files-change-when-switching-from-lighttable-to)

Thanks,

TheCube

Comment: Would have commented on the original question but I need 50 reputation. I'm allowed to ask a question though..

Comment: The related questions, [What processing is done on RAW files in the camera?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/77983), and [What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271), provide a lot of background for some of your questions.

Comment: Also related: [Why can software correct white balance more accurately for RAW files than it can with JPEGs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100925/15871) and [RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871) and [Why are my RAW images already in colour if debayering is not done yet?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/81761/15871)

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks for the links

Comment: This resolved my issue thanks.