# Why Does RAW Image Look Dark and Grainy in Meshroom?

Tags: photography-basics

[image: Meshroom Raw Comparison]

> Left - Meshroom image viewer | Right - Windows RAW image extension

Hello!

I am attempting to use Meshroom to convert this clay creature into a 3D object.

The issue I am facing however is that the RAW images look dark and grainy once I import them into Meshroom.

When I view them in the Windows RAW Image Extension they look great! - Full of detail and color.

My main questions I'm looking to answers for is:

- Why is this happening?
- Is Meshroom going to actually render the photos correctly even though they look low quality in the image viewer?
- If it will render poorly, is there anything I can do to process the RAW image so that Meshroom receives the same high quality photo as seen in the RAW extension?

Thanks for anyone that might know the answers to my questions!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening NEF files on windows initially open fine but then change contrast](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/104573/opening-nef-files-on-windows-initially-open-fine-but-then-change-contrast)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! What you're seeing is expected and has brought confusion to new RAW users in the past. They've asked more or less similar questions:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76351/9161 https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10715/9161
https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13091/9161
Hope you'll find this site helpful! if you want to ask a new question, please do a  small search before to see if something similar has been asked already.

Comment: The Windows raw image extension is extracting the JPEG preview image attached to the raw file by the camera. This JPEG preview image is the camera's own interpretation of the raw image data based on the in-camera settings at the time the image was captured.