# Raw photos in Aperture 3

Tags: raw, apple-aperture

When Aperture 3 sees the raw photos on the camera for import the photos look good. Then when they are imported and Aperture processes them they then change into black or digital noise and not one is viewable. using a Nikon D80 in raw mode, Macbook pro with 2gb ram.
Can you help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Aperture changing the color of my RAW photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/why-is-aperture-changing-the-color-of-my-raw-photos)

Comment: It would help if you could post some samples. At a guess, I would say there could be something wrong with the data in your RAW files, yet the JPEG thumbnail -- which is what I believe looks good to you -- is intact. A couple of additional experiments would be to try reading the files with iPhoto or any other RAW processor.

Answer (score 2):

I use Lightroom, but I believe the effect is the same. When your camera saves the raw file, it renders a lower quality jpeg with whatever settings your camera is using. When you first open that raw file in Aperture/Lightroom etc, it shows you that preview jpeg from your camera for a few seconds before the interal processing kicks in.

If you find you prefer the original look, you can always use the software provided with your camera to process the image, but you lose the organizational and workflow benefits of Lightroom.

Comment: Aperture works the same way. It will be most apparent if you have set the camera to capture B/W. Then when you see the preview, you will see a B/W image (the preview generated by the camera). But after importing in Aperture it will be in color.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have updated aperture and have the latest patch to handle your raw files. Raw files all have different formats and aperture is updated to support these.  You may want to view the files through "finder" and see if they appear correctly as OS X can preview raw files. If you see nothing you do not have the raw support for your camera installed.